# Spring Data Flow - Maven setup using Docker Compose

Tags: spring, docker-compose, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have installed Spring data flow using docker compose, when i try to build/run something i got an error referring to `(https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): status code: 401,`.

I know that the link had permissions changed and i wanted to modify Maven remote urls used by Data Flow.

I tried to put the correct urls in this `docker-compose.yml` file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/main/src/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml

but it seems to not work, what configuration file i have to update/add?